# What is the usage of そこはそれ?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> と、先ほどよりだいぶ気安い調子で言ってみる。が、真士はすぐにむうとうなった。
>
> 確かに自然にはなったけれど、これではいつもと変わらない。別に真士は、澪と二人で出かけたことがないわけではないのだ。……いやまあ、二人きりで出かけるのとデートがどう違うのかと言われれば答えに窮してしまうのだが、**そこはそれ**、澪に『真士とデートしている』と思って欲しいのである。

I know probably it is hard to be translated, but what is the usage of the そこはそれ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a less formal variation of それはそれとして.

He doesn't have a definite answer if anyone asks how going out with someone alone and having a date with her are different, but, **that aside**, he still wants Mio to think she is having a date with him.